# Paste variable as identifier in C#

Tags: c#

i'm trying to use variable as identifier (i might call it wrong). Let me try to explain it on example (I omitted most of the SQL code):

```
class values
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>()
    {
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
    };
    string value1 = "one";
    string value2 = "two";
    string value3 = "three";
}

private void method()
{
    foreach(string element in list)
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@"+element, SqlDbType.VarChar));
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@"+element].Value = values.element;
    }
}
```

So idea is to create class with list of parameters and values in it, and then loop through all those objects adding those parameters to command and assigning values from class. The problem kicks in when i'm trying to call for value from the class using variable "element" to tell program which object it supposed to call from class

Comment: What is the problem with a List(Of SqlParameter) ?

Comment: You can't call `values.element` like that, it's not supported unless you use some fancy reflection on it. Using a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of `List<string>` would probably help you though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably be storing your values as a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) if you intend to use them this way:

```
class values
{
    IDictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "value1", "one" },
        { "value2", "two" },
        { "value3", "three" },
    };

    private void method()
    {
        foreach(var pair in list)
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@"+pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify SqlDbType to SQL server, or it's not critical?

Comment: @JagdCrab [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) will infer the SqlDbType based on the type of the value you pass in (`string` in this case). In this case, I think it will be `VarChar`, like in your example. If that's not good enough, you can use code like yours to manually specify it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper collection instead - "dynamic" variable names can only be achieved through reflection and one-offs should be avoided in most cases.

You can use normal fields/properties and still wrap them as appropriate - this is nice because a strong static type is still exposed and the values can be specified externally. For instance:

```
class values

  List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> Values {
    get {
      return new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>() {
        {"value1", value1},
        {"value2", value2},
        {"value3", value3},
      };
    }
  }

  public string value1 = "one";
  public string value2 = "two";
  public string value3 = "three";
}
```

Then you can use the `Values` *collection* to iterate the names and actual values.

---

Alternatively, `value1..n` could be properties that update an internal (`Values`, but probably a Dictionary in that case) structure.

Or, if you were really sneaky, `Values` could be generated through reflection - the difference being is the Value source is separated.